# Unable to Scroll on iphone while using sap.ui.ux3.Shell for SAPUI5 Project

Tags: javascript, iphone, sapui5

I am using a sap.ui.ux3.Shell and filling the shell canvas with a lot of data and I am able to scroll perfectly on my desktop(Laptop) using the chrome browser but for some reason the scroll doesn't work on Iphone 6(plus). The scroll does  work on Android mobiles but it just doesn't work on Iphone. Below is the code I am using. As you see below the code basically is just creating the shell and filling the shell with some test data using the for loop. This code is in the createContent method of a javascript view in SAPUI5 Project.

```
    var oShell = new sap.ui.ux3.Shell("myShell", {
         appTitle:"Promo Verification System",
            fullHeightContent : true,
            worksetItems: [new sap.ui.ux3.NavigationItem("home",{key:"sh_1",text:"Home"}),      
                           ],

        });

    for(i=0;i<1000;i++){
    oShell.addContent( new sap.m.Label({
        text : 'Admin Screenshots'
    }));
    }
      this.addContent(oShell);
```

Just so if it helps,  setting the fullHeightContent as true enables the scrolling in the browser on my laptop or desktop. But I have no idea why it doesn't work on Iphone.

Comment: Fyi, the sap.ui.ux3 library doesn't officially support iOS: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/91f072cf6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. you will need a scroll container to do this. Just add the content to the Scroll container instead of the shell and then add the scroll container to the shell. I am pasting the code below. The most important thing is that you will need to set the height of the scroll container else it won't work.

```
                var mscroll = new sap.m.ScrollContainer("mScroll", {
                   height: '600px',
                   vertical: true,
                });

            var oShell = new sap.ui.ux3.Shell("myShell", {
     appTitle:"Promo Verification System",
        fullHeightContent : true,
        worksetItems: [new sap.ui.ux3.NavigationItem("home",{key:"sh_1",text:"Home"}),      
                       ],

    });

               for(i=0;i<1000;i++){
                  mscroll.addContent( new sap.m.Label({
                  text : 'Admin Screenshots'
                  }));
                 }


                        oShell.addContent(mscroll);
                        this.addContent(oShell);
```